# CGBitmapContextCreate runtime optional nil error

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error, avfoundation, option-type

When i run the program, there was a optional that causes it to break. I was able to narrow it down to those 2 lines of code. Is there a problem within the code, and how can i fix it. Thanks!

```
let context: CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(lumaBuffer, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, grayColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)!//problematic

let dstImageFilter: CGImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)!
```

but here is the relevant code:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    print("buffered")
    let imageBuffer: CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
    let width: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    let height: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    let bytesPerRow: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    let lumaBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    let grayColorSpace: CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()!
    let context: CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(lumaBuffer, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, grayColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)!//problematic

    let dstImageFilter: CGImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)!
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
        customPreviewLayer!.contents = dstImageFilter as AnyObject
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CGBitmapContextCreate` will return nil if the context can not be created because of incorrect parameters.  Since we don't have all the parameters, we can't tell you much more about why it's failing.  You might check the log messages, because it normally presents semi-useful log messages on failures.

Comment: that is the error. Thanks for helping   Jan  3 01:00:35  Camtest Filter[7488] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: set CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS environmental variable to see the details
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I've put all my code. Cloud you please help me figure out a way to solve it. Thank you so much!